# Get "Upgrade request required" from kubectl exec from Windows10/cygwin

Tags: kubernetes, cygwin, kubectl

For quite a while, I've been running kubectl v1.17 on Windows10/Cygwin to connect to the clusters for our application.  Every once in a while, I use "kubectl exec" to perform an operation within a container.  I've never had a problem doing this, until the last couple of days.

A couple of days ago, this attempt failed with "Upgrade request required".  I talked to a colleague with a similar setup, and he hadn't been seeing this error.  He was using v1.18, so I upgraded, and that seemed to fix the problem.  I then used that for a few hours yesterday with no problem.

This morning, I'm getting "Upgrade request required" again, so the "upgrade" didn't actually fix it.

From the occurrences of this on the web, I see it has something to do with the connection handshake, but that's about all I know.

Our clusters are running v1.13.5 of k8s.

I tried running the command with "-v=10" to get more info.

The actual internal curl command that gets this appears to be this (with some elisions):

> I0612 10:40:31.032729   10408 round_trippers.go:423] curl -k -v -XPOST  -H "X-Stream-Protocol-Version: v4.channel.k8s.io" -H "X-Stream-Protocol-Version: v3.channel.k8s.io" -H "X-Stream-Protocol-Version: v2.channel.k8s.io" -H "X-Stream-Protocol-Version: channel.k8s.io" -H "User-Agent: kubectl.exe/v1.18.0 (windows/amd64) kubernetes/9e99141" -H "Authorization: Bearer ..." 'https://...'

Is there anything in this that might indicate what might be going wrong here?

**Update**:

I discovered this morning that the issue is definitely related to Cygwin.  If I take the resulting "kubectl exec" command and execute in a Windows cmd shell, it works perfectly fine. No error.

A relevant portion of my "uname -a" string might be "3.1.5(0.340/5/3) 2020-06-01 08:59 x86_64 Cygwin".

Comment: As the official documentation states:
`kubectl is supported within one minor version (older or newer) of kube-apiserver.`:[Kubernetes.io: Version skew policy: kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/version-skew-policy/#kubectl).
Please try to use kubectl with a version most similiar to your Kubernetes cluster (in that case 1.13). Additionally please take a look here: [Github.com: Kubernetes: kubectl conventions](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-cli/kubectl-conventions.md#principles).

Comment: Just this morning, I managed to resolve this.  I had tested this with version 1.13.5 of kubectl, exactly matching the cluster version, but it didn't work. However, when I tried moving to version 1.14.0, it worked again.